# rails polymorphic association on 1 model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

Does rails provide multiple polymorphic association. And allow has_many relation.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :icon, polymorphic: true 
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, as: :image
  has_many :pictures, as: :icon
end
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried it ? Seems to me like it would work as long as Picture has image_id, image_type and icon_id, icon_type

Comment: I am using this for rails admin gem. It wasn't working.

Comment: Better put all that info the question - what isn't working (paste the error stack)

Answer (score 0):

Rails' active record does allow you to define a polymorphic association.

From the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations):

```rb
class Picture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pictures, as: :imageable
end
```